# Improve code style

Tags: code-review

I want to calculate `r, theta and phi`.

My code is very ugly. How would you propose to obtain the same results?

```
rStep = 2;
nCells = 3;
dTheta = 4;
dPhi = 5;

repmap = Table[Table[Range[nCells]*rStep, nCells], nCells]

{{{2, 4, 6}, {2, 4, 6}, {2, 4, 6}}, {{2, 4, 6}, {2, 4, 6}, {2, 4, 
   6}}, {{2, 4, 6}, {2, 4, 6}, {2, 4, 6}}}

flatten = 
 repmap[[All, #1, #]] & /@ Range[Length[repmap]] & /@ 
  Range[Length[repmap]]

{{{2, 2, 2}, {4, 4, 4}, {6, 6, 6}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {4, 4, 4}, {6, 6, 
   6}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {4, 4, 4}, {6, 6, 6}}}

r = Flatten[flatten]

{2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, \
4, 6, 6, 6}

repmap2 = 
 Table[Table[(Range[nCells] - 1)*dTheta - Pi/2, nCells], nCells] // N

{{{-1.5708, 2.4292, 6.4292}, {-1.5708, 2.4292, 6.4292}, {-1.5708, 
   2.4292, 6.4292}}, {{-1.5708, 2.4292, 6.4292}, {-1.5708, 2.4292, 
   6.4292}, {-1.5708, 2.4292, 6.4292}}, {{-1.5708, 2.4292, 
   6.4292}, {-1.5708, 2.4292, 6.4292}, {-1.5708, 2.4292, 6.4292}}}

flatten2 = repmap2[[All, All, #]] & /@ Range[Length[repmap2]]

{{{-1.5708, -1.5708, -1.5708}, {-1.5708, -1.5708, -1.5708}, {-1.5708, \
-1.5708, -1.5708}}, {{2.4292, 2.4292, 2.4292}, {2.4292, 2.4292, 
   2.4292}, {2.4292, 2.4292, 2.4292}}, {{6.4292, 6.4292, 
   6.4292}, {6.4292, 6.4292, 6.4292}, {6.4292, 6.4292, 6.4292}}}

theta = Flatten[flatten2]

{-1.5708, -1.5708, -1.5708, -1.5708, -1.5708, -1.5708, -1.5708, \
-1.5708, -1.5708, 2.4292, 2.4292, 2.4292, 2.4292, 2.4292, 2.4292, \
2.4292, 2.4292, 2.4292, 6.4292, 6.4292, 6.4292, 6.4292, 6.4292, \
6.4292, 6.4292, 6.4292, 6.4292}

repmap3 = Table[Table[(Range[nCells] - 1)*dPhi, nCells], nCells]

{{{0, 5, 10}, {0, 5, 10}, {0, 5, 10}}, {{0, 5, 10}, {0, 5, 10}, {0, 5,
    10}}, {{0, 5, 10}, {0, 5, 10}, {0, 5, 10}}}

flatten3 = repmap3[[All, #, All]] & /@ Range[Length[repmap3]]

{{{0, 5, 10}, {0, 5, 10}, {0, 5, 10}}, {{0, 5, 10}, {0, 5, 10}, {0, 5,
    10}}, {{0, 5, 10}, {0, 5, 10}, {0, 5, 10}}}

Phi = Flatten[flatten3]

{0, 5, 10, 0, 5, 10, 0, 5, 10, 0, 5, 10, 0, 5, 10, 0, 5, 10, 0, 5, \
10, 0, 5, 10, 0, 5, 10}
```

Comment: Besides the example (thanks for that), can you explain what are you trying to achieve in general?

Comment: Finally I want to calculate the so called pair correlation function of 3d data points using spherical coordinates. I have uploaded a matlab solution of a colleague, which I am trying to convert to Mathematica. This  part now produces the same results as in matlab and is the basis for the rest of his code. Please see: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KII7-EbuTd_eBI_4I0EKH-eKW8enCN7M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Just as a quick thing, any time you use `Table[Table[..., nCells], nCells]` this may be more compactly expressed as `ConstantArray[..., {nCells, nCells}]` and likely more quickly constructed as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer doesn't make any attempt to understand the problem being solved, but instead to generically replace the array constructs with ones that are (hopefully) easier to comprehend. The results should be identical to the code provided in the question.

```
repmap = ConstantArray[Range[nCells] rStep, {nCells, nCells}];
r2 = Flatten[Transpose[repmap, {3, 1, 2}]];
repmap2 = 
  ConstantArray[(Range[nCells] - 1) dTheta - Pi/2, {nCells, nCells}];
theta2 = Flatten[Transpose[repmap2, {3, 2, 1}]] // N;
repmap3 = ConstantArray[(Range[nCells] - 1) dPhi, {nCells, nCells}];
phi2 = Flatten[repmap3, {1, 2, 3}];
```

I used `r2`, `theta2`, and `phi2` so that the results could be directly compared via:

```
{r == r2, theta == theta2, Phi == phi2}
```

Which should return `{True, True, True}`.

Looking at this bit by bit:

I used `ConstantArray[..., {nCell, nCell}]` instead of `Table[Table[..., nCell], nCell]`, because there is no actual iteration over a variable here. Instead, this is just constructing several copies of the same list, which `ConstantArray` is designed for. The use of `ConstantArray` also signals that the core elements of this construct are all the same semantically, which should help in remembering what's going on.

It turns out that the complicated expressions in the `repmap` terms are all various tensor transposes. I found these transpose matches by brute force, but practically speaking it is just swapping the position of various dimensions within the tensors. It also turns out that `repmap3` does not need any transposition, and can be `Flatten`ed directly.

Because the `Transpose` expressions are so much shorter, I omitted the `flatten` intermediates entirely and simply included the `Flatten` outside of the `Transpose`.